# Google etc. and lists of links?

Tags: seo, html

On my website I have a Page A that uses an HTML/JS/PHP form to allow users to choose three things:

1. a video game
2. a style or skin
3. a keyboard layout for several countries

The form then spawns a Page B showing a diagram of the keyboard controls for that game/country/skin combination.

Since the page is generated using a form, there are no direct HTML links to each diagram on my site. They do have unique URLs, however, and people can still link to the individual diagram pages if they want to.

My question is in regards to search engine optimization. Can Google etc. crawl all these diagrams using the form? Or, should I create a Page C with direct HTML links to the diagrams (minus the skin and country choices)? IIRC, search engines don't like pages with nothing but long lists of links on them.

What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Google does submit some forms, your best bet for them to find that content is to use an [XML Sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/). It is intended for telling search engines where to find your content, particularly content that cannot be reached via links.

Creating an HTML sitemap would be fine, too. Search engines don't like lists of links when they're used as content. But providing users with a way to navigate your site and find your content is acceptable and common. So if you want your users to find this content without using your forms then you can create one of these, too. But if you don't want users to do this then avoid this option. (Don't make one and only make it available to search engines. They don't like that).

Comment: Is there a way to generate a XML sitemap using PHP? Is there a size limit for this file? The list of items I want to add is pretty long.

Comment: Dynamic sitemaps are common. As long as your script produces valid XML  that's all that matters. If your sitemap is huge it would need to be broken up into pieces. That link I provided should give more detail into that.